# why does c++ unique_ptr with incomplete types compile?

Tags: c++

I want to use unique_ptr with an incomplete type. The code below does what I expected and **can't** compile.

```cpp
#include <memory>
struct bar;
struct foo {
    foo() {

    }
    ~foo() {

    }
    std::unique_ptr<bar> pb{};
};
int main() {
    foo f;
}
```

However, if I add the definition of bar **after** the function main's definition. It **can** compile.

```cpp
#include <memory>
struct bar;
struct foo {
    foo() {

    }
    ~foo() {

    }
    std::unique_ptr<bar> pb{};
};
int main() {
    foo f;
}

struct bar {

};
```

I have no idea why the definition after main can help main compile. Is that behavior defined in c++ standard?

Comment: Your chode leads to UB because of double destruction. Never do `f.~foo();`.

Comment: If in your first example the pointer is incremented, e.g. `pb += 1;` or `pb++;`, how many bytes is the pointer advanced by? In the 2nd example, the compiler knows how big a `bar` object is.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why the compiler know how "bar" is when I define "main"? "bar" is defined after "main", I think it should not influence "main".

Comment: @273K well, "f.~foo()" don't have much relation to the question. I will remove it.

Comment: The only use of `unique_ptr` on an incomplete type is limited as specified here [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) It is generally used to refer to an object allocated with `new` (for which the compiler needs to know "how big").

Comment: I have tried another simplified example [link](https://godbolt.org/z/5YdcdGxG3), seems it is relating to template initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The first program is ill-formed. The second program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

`std::unique_ptr` does allow instantiation with an incomplete type, which is why using it as a member in `foo` is ok.

However both the definitions of the constructor and destructor of `foo` *potentially invoke* the destructor of `pb` which in turn invokes the default deleter `std::default_delete<bar>`. This requires `bar` to be a complete type.

This means you must make `bar` complete before you define the two functions. So you need to define them outside the class and put the definition of `bar` before both of these definitions:

```
#include <memory>

struct bar;

struct foo {
    foo();
    ~foo();
    std::unique_ptr<bar> pb{};
};

struct bar {
};

foo::foo() { }
foo::~foo() { }

int main() {
    foo f;
}
```

In the first program the default deleter's `operator()` will be implicitly instantiated, but `bar` will be incomplete at all possible points-of-instantiation, so that the compiler is required to diagnose the issue, e.g. with an error message.

In the second program, there is a possible point-of-instantiation at the end of the translation unit (in addition to the point explained above) where `bar` is complete. A diagnostic is not required if two possible points-of-instantiation would give different results.